# A full blown Windows (non-PE) live CD

Tags: windows-10, boot, iso-image, livecd, ramdisk

I stumbled on this somewhat obscure developer that goes by the name NTDEV & his stripped down Windows 10: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odXqeI2r5tI. Looks like his link for tiny10 is down & only live10 remains. But, no worries, as live10 is what I'm after. As, I want a full-blown Window Live CD for completely switching OSes for testing third party software.

So I downloaded & unpacked the [`live10 2GB.iso`](https://mega.nz/file/fhd1lK6R#Jq0USPFPK6dxxb7W1dnoNFg5WOI_HYaonmngwG65lMw):
[image]

Looks like `live10.vhd` wraps the filesystem underneath (I don't know that much about it). So, I had to take all the files & folders, & adding a boot binary, compiled it altogether into a  bootable ISO. Extracting the files & folders & then adding it to a compilation is straight forward. The problem was where was the binary to be added to make the ISO bootable. In typical Windows installation media it's `\boot\etfsboot.com`. So I looked into the `\boot` folder:
[image]

The closest suspect is the single file in folder en-US named `bootmgr.exe.mui`, which by the name suggests, might be the first stage bootloader. Was I correct about this? This might confirm it (forgive my tablet's resolution):
[image]
[image]

The fact that it got up to `winload.exe` means the proper binary was loaded on the first stage.

And... So, that's the farthest I got with the guy's release. Have I yet done anything wrong that caused failure to boot? There's the `menu.lst` inside the original `live10 2GB.iso` that I completely ignored:

[image]

The commands resemble linux command, but as far as I know, are not.

How do I get further & boot this?

Comment: What's wrong with the original ISO you've downloaded? `.mui` files are translation packs.

Comment: the windows 10 and 11 bootloaders will boot VHDs. I would guess he's modified the iso to boot a VHD instead of a WIM?

Comment: What are you saying that I should take a Windows installation media & replace the `installl.wim` with `live10.vhd`?

Comment: Voting to leave open (barely), but it could definitely use some improvement on the wording.  @TempusNomen For starters, I would suggest a bit of a "short summary" of the question at the top, then go into the details.

Comment: Question:  Why don't you just virtualise with oraclebox or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the Windows 10 ISO to Live Windows
(or Windows To Go) using the program WinToUSB.

Download it from
[here](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html).
Its description is found in
[What is Windows To Go?](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en-US/What-is-Windows-To-Go.html).